# How to provide connection string dynamically for azure table storage/blob storage in Azure data factory Linked service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Dynamically changing the connection string for Tablestorage  or blob storage in Azure data factory. Currently, I could see such option for database related dataset? How to achieve the same in Table or Blob storage

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you wanted. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services
As doc mentioned, UI only supports 8 linked service. For others, you could change json code directly following the same pattern.

```
{
"name": "AzureBlobStorage12",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "parameters": {
        "accountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "accountKey": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=@{linkedService().accountName};AccountKey=@{linkedService().accountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;"
    }
}
```

}

[image]
You can't put the entire connection string as an expression. You need parameterize every part separately. Make sure you noticed the prameters field. 
And then every time you use the linked service, you will be able to pass different values to it.

Comment: Can we parameterize at linked service level for blob storage? Do you have any example for the same?

Comment: We have created sample to do copy activity from Blob storage to SQL dynamically                  -We are able to parameterize at table storage level, we would like to parameterize at connection string level(Linked service level)

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Fang Liu. Now, I am able to parameterize Blob storage. Now, I am facing one more challenge, I am able to call the pipeline via Post man, I need to send Encyrpted SAS token or encrypted Storage Key to make it work. Is there a work around to send actual SAS token or Storage Key to post/trigger the pipeline.

Comment: What do you mean by encrypted token and actual token? I am not very familiar with that. Could you share an example?

Comment: Another thing you may want to take a look is azure key vault. You could put all the credentials into azure key vault and then just make the secret name parameteriable.

Answer (score 1):

In the New Linked service Azure table storage and Click on Advanced and check Specify Dynamic contents in JSON format
 [adf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bohzI.png)

`Copy the below JSON to make it Table Storage Parameterize :
{
    "name": "Table",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureTableStorage",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sasUri": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "@{linkedService().sasUriParam}"
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "sasUriParam": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}`