# Is there a way to create a single copy data pipeline that shares a single source data set and file system connection pointing to different drives?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

I'm attempting to deploy an azure data factory with a copy data pipeline that pulls files from one or more deployed / on-prem file system paths and dumps them in blob storage. The source file paths on the file system may span multiple different drives (e.g. - C:\fileshare1 vs D:\fileshare2) and may include network locations referenced via UNC paths (e.g. - \\localnetworkresource\fileshare3).

I'd like to configure a single local file system connection and source data set and just parameterize the linked service's host property. Then my pipeline would just iterate over a collection of file share paths and reuse the dataset and linked service connection. However, it doesn't look like there's any way to have the data set or pipeline  provide the host information to the linked service.  It's certainly possible to provide folder information from the pipeline and dataset, but that will be concatenated to the host specified in the linked service connection and therefore won't allow me access to different drives or network resources.

It was reasonably straightforward to do this by configuring separate linked service connections, data sets and pipelines for each distinct file share that needed to be included, but I'd prefer to manage a single pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parameterize linked service.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services

Currently, ADF UI only supports 8 kinds of linked service parameterization. But actually all the linked service are supported in ADF Runtime. You could use json code to do it. 
Refer these two post here:

[Azure Data Factory - Dynamic Account information - Parameterization of Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56995437/azure-data-factory-dynamic-account-information-parameterization-of-connectio/56999748#56999748)

[How to provide connection string dynamically for azure table storage/blob storage in Azure data factory Linked service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932728/how-to-provide-connection-string-dynamically-for-azure-table-storage-blob-storag/56934195#56934195)